# Excel sumif based on a changing critia

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have tried using the `SUMIF( INDEX( MATCH(` function to bring back the total value of two criteria, a row that is constant and a column that changes as I enter a month,

```
=IFERROR(SUMIF(Budget!$D$8:$D$62,
  $B9,
  INDEX(Budget!$R$8:$AC$62,
    MATCH($I$1,Budget!$R$6:$AC$6,0),0)),0)
```

this is only bringing back the first data entry it finds in the row, how can bring back the total number. I have been advised to use SUMIFS but I'm not sure how to include the column to be used based on the month entered.

Comment: could you mock up data and expected output that shows the problem?  My guess is you will need a SUMPRODUCT to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you mention your column changes hence using `INDEX` and `MATCH`,

But the match is done for the `ROW` of the `INDEX`, not the `COLUMN`,

I may be wrong but try this:

```
=IFERROR(SUMIF(Budget!$D$8:$D$62,$B9,INDEX(Budget!$R$8:$AC$62,0,MATCH($I$1,Budget!$R$6:$AC$6,0))),0)
```